# SQL select where but only check if parameter is true

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, if-statement

I want to select some variables from my sql datbase using a Select statement to check each element against some paramaters like:

```
  public ActionResult Filter_Rooms(bool pFilter, int pCapacity, bool pBeamer, bool pNote, bool pTelevision, bool pTel, bool pWifi)
    {
     using (var sampleDB = db)
        {
         if (pFilter)
            {
                var maxCap = pCapacity + 20;
                IQueryable<RoomViewModel> rooms = sampleDB.Spaces
                          .ToList()
                          .Where(r => (r.roomCapacity >= pCapacity 
                             && r.roomCapacity <= maxCap) 
                             && r.roomBeamer == pBeamer 
                             && r.roomCapacity == pCapacity 
                             && r.roomTelevision == pTelevision)
                          .ToList()
                          .Select(room => new RoomViewModel()
```

Where the different parameters are boolean values except for the pCapacity.

With these parameters I'm checking which record of my db (= a room) has the given parameters (= equipment). But only the parameters with boolean value true are important here. parameters with boolean value false are actually transparant cause these rooms don't have to have this paramater but it doesn't matter if they do...

Now currently I'm checking off rooms that have the true parameters and don't have the false paramaters but the false parameters should be ignored.

So ex: pBeamer = true, pNote = true, pTelevision = true, pTelephone = true BUT pWifi = false so a room with a beamer, note, television, telephone and NO wifi is ok but a room with beamer, note, television, telephone AND wifi is also ok!

Now I can't believe that I have to check each and every boolean in order to make up the select statement so is there some solution to do this fast and easy?

Comment: That is probably the best way, yes. Unless you want to use reflection to iterate all columns in your table and check for their type which is a heavy and time consuming operation. Why don´t you write a stored procedure instead and use that in your EF context?

Comment: fyi you should not just do this `using (var sampleDB = db)` it will dispose and any other methods using it, will fail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the fact that LINQ is lazy and query is not executed until you enumerate the results. There is a pattern for problems like yours:

```
var maxCap = pCapacity + 20;
var query = sampleDB.Spaces
          .Where(r => r.roomCapacity >= pCapacity && r.roomCapacity <= maxCap);

if(pBeamer)
    query = query.Where(r => r.roomBeamer);
if(pCapacity)
    query = query.Where(r => r.roomCapacity);
// ...

var rooms = query.Select(r => new RoomViewModel() //...);
```

PS. Calling `ToList()` on `db.Spaces` directly brings the entire table into application memory, and makes all the filtering happen as LINQ to Objects query. It's definitely not something you want to happen...